# Unity Dash Flickers Instead of Opening

Tags: unity, unity-dash, flicker

When I hit the meta key or click on the dash button, the dash will open very, very briefly and then immediately close. It is so quick I cannot read anything in the dash, let alone click anything. Logging out/rebooting will return it to normal functionality for a while, but it eventually resumes this odd behavior.

Comment: i have same problem after using any application with wine, before i use wine dash works normally.
do you use wine before problem occures?

Comment: It has been almost a year, but no. I don't use wine. I ended up giving up on Ubuntu and moving to Manjaro with KDE.